# Get correspondence between flat and depth images from .oni file

Tags: c++, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library

I have a video captured from Kinect in an .oni file
I can extract an RGB image from it then find a feature on the image.
What I need to do then is to find a point in 3D that corresponds to my point on 2D image.
Is this possible?
(I am going to be using C++)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. In openni 2 there is a class call `CoordinateConverter`, there is no direct function from RGB -> World coordinates though.... but if you have the correspondance in the depth image this should class could work. Also, I am almost sure that if the image registration is done the x,y points with valid depth should be the same x,y from the image.

I hope this helps, if you use openni 1 just tell me